# PySpark filter a dataframe and write data frame to mysql database

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, export

I am trying to write data frame to MySql DB and using Apache Spark 2.3.1. It has 20K to 30K rows reading from mySql and partitioned with 20 partitions. I am filtering data frame first and trying to write the filtered result set to mysql DB.

But write operation becomes too slow. Without filtering df write operation is executing as expected speed and performance. Can anyone help ?

My Code:

```
dataFrame = spark.read.format('jdbc').option(...).load()
//performing some operations and adding new column "total" in data frame

filteredDF = dataFrame.filter(dataFrame.total >= 5000)
//no_of_partitions is 20

filteredDF.write.format('jdbc').options().save()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Can you cache your Dataframe before filter operation ? And check if your code runs as in expected time.

Comment: I did tried that even, but seems issue with parallelism. Current the job is getting processed on single core. So may be due to that and use of broadcast was inappropriately handled, which i then recorrected and resolved issue.